# Python Decorator pass additional parameters to wrapped function?

Tags: python-3.x, python-decorators

How can I create a value in my decorator and pass that value to the decorated function? I am assuming I need to modify kwargs at some point, but not sure where this is done?

I have a decorator similar to the following, which I am borrowing from a tutorial:

```
from flask import request


def check_user_agent(allowed_agents):
    def inner_decorator(f):
        def wrapped(*args, **kwargs):
            if request.user_agent.string.lower() not in allowed_agents:
                abort(401, "This agent is not allowed")
            return f(*args, **kwargs)
        return wrapped
    return inner_decorator
```

This is called as follows:

```
@check_user_agent(['curl'])
def get(lc_agent = None):
    return {'message':'Gotten'}
```

I am trying to pass the value of request.user_agent.string.lower() to f, along with any other parameters might already be getting passed, but am not sure how to add it to the list of parameters?

Comment: are you saying that `request` is expected to be in `kwargs` or positionally in `args`?

Answer (score 0):

If `requests` is being passed to `get()` in some capacity already, then you can certainly use it (though it might not be called `"requests"` inside the context of your decorator).  Does this example help?

```py
def check_user_agent(allowed_agents):
    def inner_decorator(f):
        def wrapped(*args, **kwargs):
            if args[0] == "foo":
                print(f"found item {args[0]} in args")
            if kwargs["bar"] == "bar":
                print(f"found item {kwargs['bar']} in kwargs")
            return f(*args, **kwargs)
        return wrapped
    return inner_decorator

@check_user_agent(['curl'])
def get(foo, bar=None):
    return f"foo: {foo} bar: {bar}"

print(get("foo", bar="bar"))
```

That will give you:

```
found item foo in args
found item bar in kwargs
foo: foo bar: bar
```

Comment: This may have been a bad example - request is coming from `flask.request`. What I am trying to do is basically pass `agent: request.user_agent.string.lower()` as an additional element on the kwargs I am passing to `f()`, in case the wrapped function needs to do something with that value.